# SQLServer:SSIS Pipeline 13.0 is missing in Performance Counter

Tags: performance, logging, ssis, ssis-2016, performance-monitor

i want to monitor my SSIS packages performance through Performance Monitor but SQLServer:SSIS Pipeline 13.0 is miss in Available Counter section.

See screen shot below

[image]

how can i add it?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that info about perofrmance counters is get missed somehow.
Go to Administrative CMD Shell and execute the following command for your SSIS 2016

> lodctr "c:\program files\microsoft sql server"\130\dts\binn\perf-DTSPipeline130DTSPERF.INI
>   lodctr "c:\program files\microsoft sql server"\130\dts\binn\perf-DTSPipeline130DTSSVCPERF.INI

Comment: thanks for the response, although i dont find perf-DTSPipeline130DTSPERF.INI,perf-DTSPipeline130DTSSVCPERF.INI files inside the binn folder, can you help how can i add these files?

Comment: @AnkitTyagi, if you did not find the files mentioned - please check installation of SSIS on the server, and repeat or repair SSIS installation.